Round zero decimal places for a numpy.float64 - python
I want to round a float value when the decimal is .0. For all other values, I want to keep the decimal value to 1 place.
Using below, data1 equals 50.0. I want it to be 50. Although data1 should equal 37.5.
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

print(round((data1.id.eq('a1').sum() /
  (data1.id.eq('a1').sum() + data1.id.eq('a2').sum()).round(2) * 100), 0))


data2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

print(round((data2.id.eq('a1').sum() /
  (data2.id.eq('a1').sum() + data2.id.eq('a2').sum()).round(2) * 100), 0))


If you are okay with saving data intermediately, you can do it this way:

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

result = (data1.id.eq('a1').sum() / (data1.id.eq('a1').sum() + data1.id.eq('a2').sum())) * 100

# Here is how you can check!
result = int(result) if int(result) == result else result

print(result)

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

result = (data2.id.eq('a1').sum() /(data2.id.eq('a1').sum() + data2.id.eq('a2').sum())) * 100

result = int(result) if int(result) == result else result

print(result)


do note that python is subject to the same oddities about floating point numbers as any other language. See for example :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html


If you want to deal with "rounding a number to 1 decimal place" in a consitent way, I would suggest to

keep working with numbers, without trying to round(), for your computations,
deal with rounding and formatting only when you want to output your number, and do it on the string representation:

def str_rounded(value):
    # str representation,
    # rounded to 1 decimal place, drop trailing ".0" if any
    s = f"{value:.1f}".rstrip(".0")
    return s


def my_work():
    data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

    percentage = (data1.id.eq('a1').sum() /
      (data1.id.eq('a1').sum() + data1.id.eq('a2').sum()) * 100
    print(str_rounded(percentage))


    data2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], 
                 'label' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1']})

    percentage = (data2.id.eq('a1').sum() /
      (data2.id.eq('a1').sum() + data2.id.eq('a2').sum()) * 100
    print(str_rounded(percentage))




Calculate the ratio.
Check if the number ends with .0
Convert the numbers ending with .0 to integer.

Should look something like this:
import pandas as pd
def custom_round(value):
    rounded_value = round(value, 1)
    if rounded_value %1 == 0:
        return int(rounded_value)
    return rounded_value

Hopefully it help you out .

Thanks. Was aiming to avoid using logic but thought it might end at this. Was thinking it could be a quick rounding fix though
